# Alt + f4 tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать так, чтобы окно нельзя было закрыть комбинацией Alt + f4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823227/how-to-bind-alt-f4-with-python-tkinter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте забиндить эту комбинацию:

```bsh
pip3 install keyboard
```

```
import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey("alt + f4", lambda: None, suppress =True)
```

Comment: А это будет работать за пределами программы и как потом всё вернуть